# I need help understanding how JavaScript and html5 communicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, communication

I am new to coding and have decided to learn html5 and JavaScript by making a Google Chrome extensions. In order to do so I need to figure out how they communicate properly. I understand html is the visuals of the extension and JavaScript is the background processes, but there are certain things I'm still having trouble with. A brief example would be printing the outcome of a JavaScript code to make it show up in html.

Another example is this issue I'm having:
I'm trying to create a save button that saves multiple input text boxes at the same time. I have figured out how to save one text box, but not multiple. (I do use jQuery)
Here is the html code:

```
<td>first name: <span id="iFN">___</span><input type="text" id="FN"></td>
<td>last name: <span id="iLN">___</span><input type="text" id="LN"></td>
<input type="submit" id="save">
```

My Javascript code so far:

```js
$(function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get('iFN', (function(sa) {
    $('#iFN').text(sa.iFN);
  }))

  $('#Save').click(function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('iFN', (function(sa) {
      var firstname = "";
      if (sa.iFN) {
        firstname = sa.iFN;
      }
      var firstname2 = $('#FN').val();
      if (firstname2) {
        firstname = firstname2;
      }
      chrome.storage.sync.set({
        'iFN': firstname
      });
      $('#iFN').text(firstname);
      $('#FN').val('');
    }))
  })

})
```

I've tried multiple ideas to have it save last name too, but without creating multiple buttons for every single input text box, I don't know how to get it to save multiple things.

Any help would be appreciated because while I understand how to code in a JavaScript console and html console separately, it's proving... difficult to do so in a console that uses both.

Comment: there is no "communication" as such. HTML is merely presentational but exposes what is known as the Document Object Model ( DOM ) and it is through the DOM that much of what you do with Javascript will work.

Comment: Don't use jQuery, if you want to understand the basics. Instead use `document.querySelectorAll` and iterate over the result list.